# Is MLA Humanities Commons a valid alternative to Academia.edu etc.?

Tags: online-publication, social-media, networking, research-dissemination

I've recently discovered MLA's [Humanities Commons](https://hcommons.org/) network and its [CORE repository](https://hcommons.org/core/). It seems a viable non-profit alternative for sharing and preserving scholarly work to commercial ventures such as Academia.edu or Researchgate, whose downsides ([1](https://kfitz.info/academia-not-edu/), [2](https://dariahopen.hypotheses.org/878)) are well known. Does it represent an effective venue for disseminating one's own work?

Comment: Your question is a little bit too broad, so I would kindly ask that you narrow to a more specific question. What is your main concern with MLA as a platform? I use it and it is 100% legit. The main difference is that they are far more concerned about legal repercussions. Academia/ResearchGate will let you upload almost anything, no questions asked. MLA will have a staff of students to verify if your upload is really a preprint and that you have the legal right to upload the paper. So it can take a few days to 2 weeks until your upload is public.

Comment: Thanks, @djohn, for your comment. I had no specific concern, I was just trying to get some general feedback about how its features. The downsides of commercial products such as Academia.edu are well known [(https://kfitz.info/academia-not-edu/)], so I was looking for a viable non-profit alternative. I'll try to rephrase the question though!

Comment: I don't see why this is opinion-based. Asking how Academia.edu is perceived in comparison to the ArXiv wouldn't be considered off topic either.